# Android Studio Error While Building APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am be making the final version of an app with the following **Gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.garsah.information"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'


}
```

However, I get this error:

```
Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.1).
```

I searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.1.1/intellij-core-26.1.1.jar

[image: img]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had this problem for like a month or so, messing around settings and found this. just check this ("Enable embedded Maven repository") and enjoy.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll get this error if your gradle plugin is no longer available.

Update your gradle plugin to the latest version. Open `build.gradle` for the project (not the app) and find the following line:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

Check the [latest available plugin version here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle) and update it. For me it was:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

You may also need to update your gradle version in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`. Update the following line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the tools where ever you would like, including in your home directory, you just need to make sure that $ANDROID_HOME points to where that is and that the PATH uses the $ANDROID_HOME variable (remember, order is important here). You can evaluate your current "PATH" by running echo $PATH.

Assuming the permissions are corrected and that your PATH is as you specified, you should have no problem running android since the android command should be in the /opt/Android/Sdk/tools directory. If you continue to have problems, I may recommend installing the larger Android Studio which might take care of some things for you, including permissions and SDK location.

Also put this lines on your app build.gradle file,

```
lintOptions {
    disable "ResourceType"
}
```

Comment: delete this buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'